# How would I create a gradient background like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I need to replace the vessel seen in the below image with another vessel. I have already cropped the vessel that needs to be placed there however I am unsure how to create the gradient background seen in the below picture with the bar in the middle. I see that there's a gradient and some lighter 'spots' but I am at a loss how to create this effect in Adobe Photoshop.

[image: background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to tackle this in Photoshop, I'd first use the gradient tool (keyboard shortcut: 'G'). Both ends would be black and the center would be the lighter blue.

Next I'd use the brush tool with a feather brush (keyboard shortcut: 'B'), and paint the sides. For the center lighter blue I'd use a feather brush with the light color. Alternatively you could create an ellipse (Keyboard shortcut: 'U' or Shift +'U' to cycle to the ellipse shape) and put one in position. Then go to Filter > Blue > Gaussian blur and adjust the radius until you're happy with the look.

As for the rectangle running through the middle, draw a rectangle (Keyboard shortcut 'U') the length you want it to go. Use a black fill, and then drop the opacity. To make it fade like it does when near the boat use the gradient tool again (Keyboard shortcut: 'G') and change the Gradient fill to go from black to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I would build the background with four basic layers:

1) A gradient for the "sky"

2) A gradient for the "sea" (basically inverse of the sky)

3) A line for the "horizon" (draw a line and experiment with gaussian blur to soften it a bit"

4) A highlight behind the ship; draw a rough outline with the lasso, feather it a bit, fill with white, adjust transparency, maybe blur a bit

Answer (score -3):

Check out this video:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cgTdYPBGX8)

*it explains how to use gradient background*

Comment: Please explain the method here instead of just linking to another site. This site aims to be the place to find the answers. When your link dies one day this post will loose its meaning.